# Create a Winter Bash 2015 hat reminder

Tags: code-golf, date

**Input**

Two dates, each comprising of a month (Dec or Jan) and a day (01-31). These will be given as 4 integers (`12 01 01 01`, for example), in any reasonable format you choose (leading zeroes, no leading zeroes, list, individual inputs, list of lists, etc.). The first date is supposed to represent today's date.

**Output**

- If the second input date is Dec 14, output `Sufganiyot`
- If it is Dec 18, output `A new hope`
- For Dec 23, `The airing of grievances`
- For Dec 25, `O Tannenbaum`
- For Dec 31 or Jan 1, `Auld Lang Syne`
- Otherwise output `Try some other day!` (in which case you will not compare the dates, see below)

This is followed by

- `, Go and get it!` if the first and second input dates are same.
- `, Wait for it!` if the first date comes before the second date.
- `, But you missed it!` if the first date comes after the second date.

**Sample runs**

`Dec 23 Dec 23` -> `The airing of grievances, Go and get it!`

`Dec 28 Jan 1` -> `Auld Lang Syne, Wait for it!`

`Dec 18 Dec 17` -> `Try some other day!`

`Jan 25 Dec 25` -> `O Tannenbaum, But you missed it!`

**Score**

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: You should be more prescriptive about the date format. "Any other format" is open to all kinds of misinterpretation. Is `1225` for Christmas Day and `0101` for New Years day acceptable? I could even say that my program uses a "format" where December 18 is represented by `A new hope`

Comment: What do you mean "for convenience"?  How many bytes do you get for free?

Comment: @NotthatCharles I think he means all the characters in the strings. However it would be nice to have them added up in the question. Also, it's not clear whether quote marks around the strings are free or not (my preference would be that they are, because the tricks people do to avoid quote marks would confuse the scoring a lot.)

Comment: @steveverrill So the only parts to golf are: 1) Comparing dates, and 2) a switch statement, right?

Comment: @NotthatCharles If you use the date format proposed in my first comment, then it's really only point 2. In any case Dec comes alphabetically before Jan, so there isn't a lot to do here at all.

Comment: Both the date format and the final paragraph are very open to interpretation.

Comment: Please [use the Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/) before posting a challenge so due time is given to working out little details.

Comment: Glad to help. The hat was a nice bonus :)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>400</s> <s>340</s> 333 - 139 = <s>261</s> <s>201</s> 194 bytes

I considered these characters "convenient":

```
, Go and get it!, Wait for it!, But you missed it!Try some other day!Auld Lang SyneO TannenbaumThe airing of grievancesA new hopeSufganiyot
```

Here is the code (called with `s(first month number, first month date, second month number, second month date)`):

```
String s(int a,int b,int c,int d){String x="";int e=(a*b!=1)?a*b:372;if(e==372)x="Auld Lang Syne";if(e==216)x="A new hope";if(e==276)x="The airing of grievances";if(e==300)x="O Tannenbaum";if(x=="")return"Try some other day!";int f=(c==1)?372*d:c*d;return x+", "+((e>f)?"Wait for it...":(e<f)?"But you missed it!":"Go and get it!");}
```

Ungolfed:

```
static String v(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    String x="";
    int e=(a*b!=1)?a*b:372;
    if(e==372)x="Auld Lang Syne";
    if(e==216)x="A new hope";
    if(e==276)x="The airing of grievances";
    if(e==300)x="O Tannenbaum";
    if(x=="")return"Try some other day!";
    int f=(c==1)?372*d:c*d;
    return x+", "+((e>f)?"Wait for it...":(e<f)?"But you missed it!":"Go and get it!");
}
```

Comment: why do you need the static keyword? You could remove that and the space for -7 bytes.

Comment: @AshwinGupta You'll also notice that I haven't included it in the golfed declaration. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 664 - 171  = 493 bytes

I consider the following strings "convenient":

```
"Sufganiyot""A new hope""The airing of grievances""O Tannenbaum""Auld Lang Syne""Auld Lang Syne"", go and get it!"", wait for it!"", but you missed it""Try some other day"
```

And the code:

```
?a:?b:?c:?d:c.12=[d.14=["Sufganiyot"a.12=[b.14=[#R,1;|b.14<[#R,2;|b.14>[#R,3;]]]|a.1=[#R,3;]]|d.18=["A new hope"|a.12=[b.18=[#R,1;|b.18<[#R,2;|b.18>[#R,3;]]]|a.1=[#R,3;]]|d.23=["The airing of grievances"|a.12=[b.23=[#R,1;|b.23<[#R,2;|b.23>[#R,3;]]]|a.1=[#R,3;]]|d.25=["O Tannenbaum"|a.12=[b.23=[#R,1;|b.23<[#R,2;|b.23>[#R,3;]]]|a.1=[#R,3;]]|d.31=["Auld Lang Syne"|a.12=[b.31=[#R,1;|b.31<[#R,2;|b.31>[#R,3;]]]|a.1=[b.1=[#R,1;|b.1<[#R,2;|b.1>[#R,3;]]]]]]]]]]|c.1=[d.1=["Auld Lang Syne"|a.1=[b.1=[#R,1;|b.1<[#R,2;|b.1>[#R,3;]]]]]|#R,4;]]$R1%a:a.1=[", Go and get it"#E;|a.2=[", Wait for it"#E;|a.3=[", But you missed it"#E;|a.4=["Try some other day"#E;]]]]@$E33!'"!"@$
```

Ungolfed:

```
~ Create a Winter Bash 2015 hat reminder
```

? a: ? b: ? c: ? d:

c. 12 =
[
  d. 14 =
  [
    "Sufganiyot"
    a. 12 =
    [
      b. 14 =
      [
        #R,1;
      | b. 14 <
        [
          #R,2;
        | b. 14 >
          [
            #R,3;
          ]
        ]
      ]
    | a. 1 =
      [
        #R,3;
      ]
    ]
  | d. 18 =
    [
      "A new hope"
    | a. 12 =
      [
        b. 18 =
        [
          #R,1;
        | b. 18 <
          [
            #R,2;
          | b. 18 >
            [
              #R,3;
            ]
          ]
        ]
      | a. 1 =
        [
          #R,3;
        ]
      ]
    | d. 23 =
      [
        "The airing of grievances"
      | a. 12 =
        [
          b. 23 =
          [
            #R,1;
          | b. 23 <
            [
              #R,2;
            | b. 23 >
              [
                #R,3;
              ]
            ]
          ]
        | a. 1 =
          [
            #R,3;
          ]
        ]
      | d. 25 =
        [
          "O Tannenbaum"
        | a. 12 =
          [
            b. 23 =
              [
                #R,1;
              | b. 23 <
                [
                  #R,2;
                | b. 23 >
                  [
                    #R,3;
                  ]
                ]
              ]
          | a. 1 =
            [
              #R,3;
            ]
          ]
        | d. 31 =
          [
            "Auld Lang Syne"
          | a. 12 =
            [
              b. 31 =
                [
                  #R,1;
                | b. 31 <
                  [
                    #R,2;
                  | b. 31 >
                    [
                      #R,3;
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
            | a. 1 =
              [
                b. 1 =
                  [
                    #R,1;
                  | b. 1 <
                    [
                      #R,2;
                    | b. 1 >
                      [
                        #R,3;
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
| c. 1 =
  [
    d. 1 =
      [
        "Auld Lang Syne"
      | a. 1 =
        [
          b. 1 =
            [
              #R,1;
            | b. 1 <
              [
                #R,2;
              | b. 1 >
                [
                  #R,3;
                ]
              ]
            ]
        ]
      ]
  | #R,4;
  ]
]

$R
  1% a:
  a. 1 =
  [
    ", Go and get it" #E;
  |
    a. 2 =
    [
      ", Wait for it" #E;
    |
      a. 3 =
      [
        ", But you missed it" #E;
      |
        a. 4 =
        [
          "Try some other day" #E;
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
@
$E33!'"!"@
$

I am never, ever, ever going anywhere near this thing ever, ever again.